# date issue in sql - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find out the names of the employee who recently join the organisation.

data:

```
emp     Date of joining

neil    31-dec-2010
tom     31-dec-2008
fred    31-dec-2011
scott   31-dec-2011
james   31-dec-2010
shane   31-dec-2011
brendon 31-dec-2010
kane    31-dec-2009
chris   31-dec-2010
matthew 31-dec-2011
```

expected output:

```
emp     Date of Joining

fred    31-dec-2011
scott   31-dec-2011
shane   31-dec-2011
matthew 31-dec-2011
```

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your issue, convert date or anything. can you give more information something about column data type, recently join in last date or last month.

Comment: What means _recently_ for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what you told us so far, this might do the job:

```
select emp, date_of_joining
from your_table
where date_of_joining = (select max(date_of_joining)
                         from emp
                        );
```

Comment: This will use 2 table/index scans - one for each `SELECT`.

Answer (score 5):

This will get the most recent joiners using only a single table scan:

```
SELECT emp,
       date_of_joining
FROM   (
  SELECT emp,
         date_of_joining,
         MAX( date_of_joining ) OVER () AS max_date
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  date_of_joining = max_date;
```

and this would get the 4 most recent joiners:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER BY date_of_joining DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 4;
```

and this would get the most recent joiner (but return multiples on ties):

```
SELECT emp,
       date_of_joining
FROM   (
  SELECT emp,
         date_of_joining,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY date_of_joining DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
SELECT emp, date_of_joining
FROM table_name
WHERE date_of_joining = (
    SELECT MAX(date_of_joining)
    FROM table_name
    );
```

Comment: This will use 2 table/index scans - one for each `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT *,Rank()OVER(order BY DOJ desc) RNO 
 FROM EMP
)A WHERE A.RNO =1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT emp Date of joining
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
Date_of_joining > '1/1/2011'
```

Check this one. add date according to you.